# PIL returning black images

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to crop an image into several small images. My code saves 4 images but they are all black squares of 1kb. Can anyone suggest what's wrong?

```
from PIL import Image,ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
import os.path

def slice(filename,desiredsize):
    name=filename.split('.')[0]
    img=Image.open('Myself.jpg')
    width,height=img.size
    nsamples=int(width/desiredsize)
    print img.size


    for i in range(nsamples):
        print "Creating slice: ", (i+1), "/", nsamples, "for", filename
        startpixel=i*desiredsize
        temp = img.crop((startpixel, 1, startpixel + desiredsize, desiredsize + 1))
        temp.save('C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\GitHub\\'+'{}_{}.jpg'.format(name,i))

slice('myself.jpg',100)
```

Comment: What were you hoping the code might do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to crop an image into several small images.

Comment: Yes, but which pixels do you want to get in the output image? The first row? The first column? The ones on the diagonal? Every 7th column?

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware of this detail. Thanks for bringing it to my notice. I don't know how to best decide which pixels I want, but I have to extract and save 128x128 samples out of the original image. How would you suggest I do that?

Comment: Neither you nor I can write any code until we have a clear understanding of what we are trying to do! When you write a clear description of your input and expected output, the answer will hopefully fall into place.

Comment: I am doing image slicing for the first time so please excuse my ignorance. I have no clear statement for an output, except for the fact that an image needs to cut into multiple smaller parts and those multiple small parts will be used to train a network later. I welcome whatever suggestion you might have. My code is inspired from here - https://github.com/despoisj/DeepAudioClassification/blob/master/sliceSpectrogram.py